# ng-model not updating for radio button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have a radio button whose model is needed by the function that is called when I hit the button below it:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="display" value="true">True <input type="radio" ng-model="display" value="false">False
    </div>
    <button>
      ....
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

However, the results never come back right. If I go in and debug the code, within the javascript **every single time** the damn value of $scope.display is "true". It doesn't have to do with me not using ng-value, based on what I have read about it, right? Previously, this element worked correctly and was not in a form/form-inline/form-group, but a simple div. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Seems to be working to be working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/G7PoSsD9nBgvFnKPb76s?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

it does work here is a pluncker: [pluncker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SnD5cOBYW0MbFkHINmCi?p=preview)

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<input type="radio" ng-model="display" value="true">true
<input type="radio" ng-model="display" value="false">
false
<br>
```

display = {{display}}